# Why setInterval wont stop?

Tags: javascript

Why **console.log(1)** gets executed here forever:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (true) {
        clearInterval(interval);

        console.log(1);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: What's the scope of `interval`? You're not explicitly closing it here.

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/6Gndb/

Comment: This works as expected (`1` is printed once) in Chrome DevTools.

Comment: Seems to work. Maybe you changed your code and it's cached the old version?

Comment: Why not just use setTimeout?

Comment: Is there a var inside your interval function with the same name as the outer var? (The example you have given should work as expected)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the scope within which you're executing this code.

If `interval` is unique within its scope — be it global or function scope — then this will work as expected.

If, however, you execute this code within a loop (for example), then you are *overwriting* `interval` with some new interval on each iteration, breaking your `clearInterval` call for all but the very last `setInterval` call:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (true) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log(1);
        }
    }, 100);
}

// ^ will give you one single console log entry,
//   and two more console log entries per second forever
```

Comment: That looks like a good answer, it is executed in a loop... Have to investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems that your variable `interval` is used somewhere again. If I run code you provided it works as expected. I guess user Lightness has given a great explaination of this, also he provided piece of code where "closure problem" is obvious (which caused you problem too). I just want to add extra information. If you want your code inside of loop + setInteval works aparat you can do the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    var o = {
        i: i,
        interval: null,
        timer: function() {
            if (true) {
                clearInterval(this.interval);
                console.log(this.i);
            }
        }
    };

    o.interval = setInterval(o.timer.bind(o), 1000);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hYy3M/)

I hope it will be useful for someone.